# Bootstrap content not rendering properly in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is awkward because everything worked fine. I opened the laptop and somehow it crashed and didn't corresponding to any commands so I had to turn it off. After I started again and after building my project(just in case anything was wrong) and opened my web page I realized that bootstrap is not working at all, and I can't figure out why because I didn't do anything. I tried to install a lower version and didn't worked and after I install the latest stable version and not didn't worked again. If you need any source code let me know and I will edit my post. I will put a picture below which describes what I am talking about(or at least I hope so).

[image]

Comment: what do you mean _"bootstrap is not working"_? What specific problems are you seeing?

Comment: @zgood Well in console I can see no error, but as you see this is a part of a default project, is the web page in the picture the same as in the default web page?Also where you see Home design should be a navbar, the default navbar , so I am meaning that is not working even I have installed and everything worked fine before my laptop suddenly crashed.

Comment: It has the appearance of running in IE Compatibility mode, even though you're on Chrome. Try refreshing your cache, rebuilding, and using a different browser.

Comment: @Jack Well that did the trick, thanks Jack, refreshing the cache in Chrome and rebuilding the project was enough. If you want you can answer to the question and I will mark you answer as correct

Comment: You can always press Control +  F5 in the browser (force a reload of the files instead of reading them from cache).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has the appearance of running in IE Compatibility mode, even though you're on Chrome. Try refreshing your cache (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>), rebuilding your project, and using a different browser.

I've run in to this issue before and refreshing the cache usually does the trick.